# Remove trailing zeroes python but with small restriction

Tags: python

Whats a good way to remove trail zeroes for:

1.0 becomes 1.0

1.00 becomes 1.0

1.4560 becomes 1.456

1.4560000 becomes 1.456

1.40 becomes 1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do nothing:

```
>>> 1.00
1.0
>>> 1.0
1.0
>>> 1.4560
1.456
>>> 1.45600000
1.456
>>> 1.40
1.4
```

Comment: >>> float(1.40000)
1.3999999999999999

>>> float(1.41000000)
1.4099999999999999    

what about this

Comment: @Adobri: that would be tricky if you have the Python version restricted. In 3.3 or 2.7 this should be fixed.

Comment: yeah want it for python 2.6

Comment: @Adobri: you could try [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/decimal.html)

Answer (score 2):

Do nothing as Kabie suggested assuming its a float or decimal.
If it's a string, use `rstrip()`

```
print '1.4000'.rstrip('0') # '1.4'
```

**Edit:**
As pointed out, this will fail for `'1.0'`. Possible fix:

```
num = '42.00'
normalized = num.strip('0')+'0' if num.rstrip('0')[-1] == '.' else num.strip('0')
print normalized # 42.0
```

Comment: Agreed. Adding a possible fix

Comment: @Kabie I am curious, what would be best if the numebr is in string format and we want to get another string which satisfies above conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [format strings](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
'{:g}'.format(float(string))
```

Or as @kabie suggested use:

```
str(float(Num))
```

Comment: `str(float(Num))` would be simpler